# Using Android vibrator seems a bit slow, what's a good strategy?

Tags: performance, kotlin

I am trying to make a relatively simple game in Kotlin with force feedback. Every time an object hits a wall I want the phone to vibrate.

Here is my code, which generally works:

```
val vibT = 0L
val vibrator: Vibrator by lazy {
    getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
}
```

and then:

```
fun bump() {
    var now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if ( vibrator.hasVibrator() && now>vibT+51) {
        vibrator.cancel()
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(50, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
        vibT = now
    }
}
```

It seems that when the code runs the bump() function in rapid succession (for example, when several objects hit the wall), it gets rather sluggish with the redraws. If I comment out the line vibrator.vibrate(...) then the game runs smoothly.

At first, I thought maybe I was just trying to call the function while it was still vibrating, hence causing a backlog of vibration requests, but even after adding in the timing check with `now` and `vibT` it's still a bit sluggish when a lot of calls are made to the function.

I'm assuming this is not a synchronous call, and that the code continues executing as soon as I've requested a vibration, but I can't find documentation to back that up.

Is there a better strategy? Maybe there are some gotcha's that I ought to be aware of when doing this?

Answer (score 1):

After testing, I saw that calls to `Vibrator::vibrate` can take up to 5 milliseconds. If you're doing it in rapid succession, this can cause slowdown, as in your case.

I wrote a helper class that moves the calls to `Vibrator::vibrate` to a background thread to avoid blocking the UI thread:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.VibrationEffect
import android.os.Vibrator
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue

/**
 * @author https://github.com/gottagofaster236
 */
class AsyncVibrator(context: Context) {
    private val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

    private val vibrationRequestsQueue = ArrayBlockingQueue<Long>(VIBRATOR_QUEUE_CAPACITY)

    private var vibrationThread: Thread? = null

    fun vibrate(lengthMs: Long) {
        vibrationRequestsQueue.offer(lengthMs)
    }

    fun start() {
        stop()
        vibrationThread = Thread(::processVibrationRequests).apply(Thread::start)
    }

    fun stop() {
        vibrationThread?.interrupt()
        vibrationThread = null
    }

    private fun processVibrationRequests() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
            val lengthMs = try {
                vibrationRequestsQueue.take()
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                break
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                vibrator.vibrate(
                    VibrationEffect.createOneShot(
                        lengthMs,
                        VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE
                    )
                )
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                vibrator.vibrate(lengthMs)
            }
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        const val VIBRATOR_QUEUE_CAPACITY = 10
    }
}
```

Usage in an Activity:

```
// import ...

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private val asyncVibrator = AsyncVibrator(this)
    
    // ...

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        asyncVibrator.start()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        asyncVibrator.stop()
        super.onPause()
    }

    fun testVibration() {
        // Vibrate for 100 milliseconds.
        asyncVibrator.vibrate(100L)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// this initiates the android vibrator [ put this on the onCreate ]
val vibe = this@MainActivity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
```

then

```
// put this where you want the vibrator to activate (fun bump*())
val vibratorService = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
vibratorService.vibrate(40)
```